# Strava API updateActivityById - Resource Not Found Error

Tags: python-3.x, strava-api-v3

I'm trying to update a Strava activity using the Strava API endpoint updateActivityById with a PUT request in Python. However, I'm consistently getting a "Resource Not Found" error. Here's my code:

```
def update_acti(idd):
   activity_write_read_all_token = ***

    url = f'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/{idd}'
    
    header = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + activity_write_read_all_token
        }
    
    data = {
        'gear_id' : user['shoes'] #shoes identifier, string
        }
    
    r = requests.put(url, headers = header, json = data).json()
    return r

response = update_acti(12345678901)
```

I get an error 404 : Ressource Not Found.

I first checked that the activity existed with getActivityById and it does.
The user['shoes'] returns the correct gear id as a string. Even with this line commented I still get the error.

Then I suppose the error comes from my PUT request "syntax" or from the access token.

The endpoint requires an activity:write and activity:read_all scope authorization to access activity no matter the privacy setting. I generated an exchange code for these two scopes with following url and got the access token.

`http://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/exchange_token&approval_prompt=force&scope=activity:write,read_all`

Do you see something I missed or have an idea on what might be causing the problem ? Thanks.

Comment: This error indicates that the server could not find the requested resource. In other words, the link you clicked on or the URL you typed into your browser (**or in this case the request in the question**) does not correspond to an active webpage on the server.

Comment: I am aware of that but thought it must linked to my request. I replicated this function in Strava's Swagger Playground (developers.strava.com/playground) which should eliminate errors I could introduce in the system. I tested this with several activities and privacy settings but none of them were successful. The same 404 error. Again. And again. At this point I resort to contact the Strava developer support to see if the could be an error server side.